How to use comparison in listenWhen while using flutter bloc with freezed?
How to use the following code while using flutter bloc with freezed.
listenWhen:{
   current is AddAssessmentState.saveAssessmentError()
}


The above code gives error "AddAssessmentState.saveAssessmentError isn't a type.
Try correcting the name to match an existing type.dartnot_a_type" .
How can I properly achieve the above requirement ?
